# Howto override a datetime_select with before_validation filter in model with correct time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, timezone

I have a form with two fields date and time that map to one db table column time (datetime). 
Field date is a string field for datepicker and time is a datetime_select. Since i am not in utc timezone i have to substract two hours in my set_date method.

How can i implement this in a more generic way?

```
# Model
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :set_date

  def set_date
    if self.date
      begin
        date = Date.strptime(self.date, '%d.%m.%Y')
      rescue
        errors.add(:date, "invalid date")
        return false
      end
      # can not get minutes by self.time.minute 
      self.time = DateTime.new(date.year, date.month, date.mday, self.time.hour.to_i, self.time.strftime("%M").to_i)
      # have to set local time manually
      self.time = self.time - 2.hours
    end
  end

# Form
<%= simple_form_for(@task) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :date, :as => :string, :input_html => { :class => 'asdatepicker'} %>    
  <%= f.input :time, :as => :datetime, :minute_step => 5,  :input_html => { :class => 'input-small'}  %>
...

# application.rb
config.time_zone = 'Berlin'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

Comment: I see you are using a datetime input to get the time. I think a time input whould be enough.

Comment: Thats right. Currently only for debugging to see if date is set correct in set_date method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the  [in_time_zone method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-in_time_zone) like this:

```
self.time = DateTime.new(2012, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0).in_time_zone("Mid-Atlantic")
# => Sun, 01 Jan 2012 08:00:00 GST -02:00
```

You can find all time zones using `rake time:zones:all`.

Regards, Dorian